# How can I build a Docker Image in Google Cloud Build and use in later Build Steps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, google-cloud-build

In my Rails project, I have a Docker Image in a repo which is used for DB migration and unit tests.  Prior to running migrations/testing, I may need to update gems on the Image.  However, it seems that even after updating Gems, the updated image (which is not pushed to the repo, but which is in a build step just prior to migration/testing) is not available to future build steps.

My cloudbuild.yaml looks like this:

```
steps:
  - id: update_gems
    name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: [ 'build', '-t', "us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/myregistry/myimage:deploy",
            '--build-arg', 'PROJECT=${PROJECT_ID}', '-f', 'docker/bundled.Dockerfile', '.' ]
  - id: db_migration
    name: "gcr.io/google-appengine/exec-wrapper"
    args: ["-i", "us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/myregistry/myimage:deploy",
           "-e", "RAILS_ENV=${_RAILS_ENV}",
           "-e", "INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME=${_INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME}",
           "-s", "${_INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME}",
           "--", "./bin/rake", "db:migrate"]
  - id: unit_test
    name: "gcr.io/google-appengine/exec-wrapper"
    args: ["-i", "us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/myregistry/myimage:deploy",
           "-e", "RAILS_ENV=test", 
           "-e", "INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME=${_INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME}",
           "-s", "${_INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME}",
           "--", "./bin/rspec"]
  - id: deploy_to_GAE
    name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
    args: ['app', 'deploy', '--project', '${PROJECT_ID}', 'app.yaml']
```

The Dockerfile referred to in the 1st step looks like this:

```
ARG PROJECT
FROM us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/${PROJECT}/myregistry/myimage:deploy
WORKDIR /workspace
ADD Gemfile* ./
RUN bundle update
RUN bundle install
```

During a triggered Cloud Build, I see it update Gems and create a new hash like so:
[image: updated gems]

And then during the `db_migration` step, I see it pulling the old image before the Gems were updated:
[image: db migration with old image]

This can be verified in the `update_gems` step logs where the pre-updated image hash matches (ie the image hash which is freshly pulled, but not yet had its Gems updated):
[image: pre-gem update]

I realize a work-around is to push the updated image after building it, which does in fact work.  For example, I could add this step after `update_gems` step:

```
  - id: update_image
    name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: [ 'push',  'us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/myregistry/myimage:deploy' ]
```

However, it begs the question why the new `udate_image` build step has access to the image built by the `update_gems` step while other future steps don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image are stored locally, in a local docker registry, that Docker can access. That's why you can push it with Docker.

But, when you use another step, such as `gcr.io/google-appengine/exec-wrapper`, Docker is no longer loaded in the runtime context and thus the local docker registry is unknown/not active.

So, the solution is:

- Either to push externally the image and then use it. Like this, it's not a local registry but an external registry which is used, and it works in any steps.
- Or install docker on your current runtime step image (or use Docker as step image and install what you need on this image) -> it will be difficult, I don't recommend this way.